javaFX toolkit not initialized while testing in junit 5
So i am making a school project with javaFX and i need to make test with junit 5. But when i try to run my test i get an ExceptionInitializeError because the "ToolKit" is not initialized. How can i initialize this toolkit?
public class RegisterTest {

    private Register register;
    private User user;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        register = new Register();
        register.username = new TextField();
        register.email = new TextField();
        register.password = new TextField();
        register.confirmPassword = new TextField();
        user = mock(User.class);

    }

    @Test
    public void testValidUser() {
        when(user.checkNewUsername(anyString())).thenReturn(true);
        when(user.checkNewEmail(anyString())).thenReturn(true);
        when(user.checkNewPassword(anyString())).thenReturn(true);

        assertTrue(register.validUser());
    }

i asked chatgtp and i gave me an initializor that runs @Beforeall. but JFXpanel comes from a library im not working with calles "swing".
@BeforeAll
    public static void initToolkit() {
        new JFXPanel(); // Initializes the JavaFX toolkit
    }


You're gonna have issues. JavaFX stuff needs to run on the FXAT thread, and your JUnit tests don't. So the idea of, "Do this, then check the answer", which is the basis ofJUnit tests isn't going to work.

@DaveB that where some mocks that i already removed. Also found the solution: BeforeAll
public static void initToolkit() {
if (!Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
Platform.startup(() -> {});
}
}

A couple of things confuse me.  I don't understand why you would have Node subclasses as fields in something not 100% layout related.  Register doesn't seem to be a layout class - but maybe it is.  That being said, none of those fields seem to be related to the test at all - so the FXAT stuff is irrelevant.  The only thing being tested here is Register.validUser(), and we don't get to see the code for that.  However, given the mocked methods, it seems likely to just call a bunch of User methods and combine the answer.  In which case, maybe Register.validUser() should be in User instead....

I'm guessing that any code that's in Register.validUser() could probably be in User.  So that Register.validUser() could just call User.isValid() or something like that.  But, if Register.validUser() is doing stuff like Register.password.getText(), then this is just a bad design.  Bad, bad, bad.  If, as I suspect, Register is actually acting as a Data Model, then the things stored in Register.userName, etc, should be just stored as data, and linked to TextFields in a layout.  Don't store the Nodes in your Data Model.  Does that make sense?

This is a personal Framework of mine which handles that scenario: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-SimpleJavaFxApplicationBase . Take a look in the package "testBase". A Guide is in the readme file. The Code handles JavaFX things on the FX thread synchronously with the test class thread. It may be not the best code, but it works and is easy to use!

Alternatively there is a library "testfx" out there, which i could not get to run in my project.

BeforeAll
public static void initToolkit() {
    if (!Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
        Platform.startup(() -> {});
    }
}


Don't forget to call Platform::exit when all tests are done. Though also keep in mind that JavaFX cannot be started again within the same JVM instance. You may want to put the startup/exit logic in your own custom extension. Register a BeforeAllCallback extension at the class level that starts JavaFX only once. Use the Store of the root ExtensionContext to keep track of if you've already started JavaFX. Use Store.CloseableResource to exit JavaFX after all tests have executed. Or you can look into the TestFX framework
